# How to extract multiple values with a regular expression in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running tests with jmeter and I need to extract with a Regular Expression:

```
insertar?sIws2kyXGJJA_01== 
insertar?sIws2kyXGJJA_02==
```

in the following String:

```
[\"EMBPAGE1_00010001\",\"**insertar?sIws2kyXGJJA_01==**\",1,100,\"%\",300,\"px\",0,\"center\",\"\",\"[\"EMBPAGE1_00010002\",\"**insertar?sIws2kyXGJJA_02==**\",1,100,\"%\",300,\"px\",0,\"center\",\"\",\"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use super secret operator (Negative match N)[image]

UPD: G2 - is in my example, as I extract two groups from each encounter.
each encounter is "uuid" in g1 and g2 is second part I need second part here.
that's why $2$ template and g2. If your encounters in one group you ll most likely use $1$ template that will place all encounters into g1.
If you have one match group you don't actually need _gN ending at all.
To understand more the variables after group extraction add a "Debug PostProcessor" and inspect output in TreeView.

It nice two know that control elements like "For each" understand groups and can work with prefix like regexUUID_ and walk through. In most cases it's next you do after extraction.

UPD2. primitive version of regexp in question (insertar\?sIws2kyXGJJA_\d*)==([^[]*)
with template $1$$2$
you ll have the first parts in g1 group and the second parts in g2

Answer (score 5):

In answer given by DMC, you need to add regular expression extractor TWICE to match/retrieve both the values with different Match No. (1, 2). Though it is also correct, suggesting better approach to achieve the same.

**Another Approach:**

**1. Capture Both Values:**

You can use Template to capture both the values **at the same time**, and later, refer it using indexing.

Please check the following screen shot:

[image]

Here, we captured both the values using two groups into two different templates, as $1$ and $2$ respectively. Here, templates store the data in the order of the groups specified in regular expression by default. (FYI, you can change the order also by tweaking the order of templates like $2$ and then $1$.)

Now, as in the diagram, we are capturing two values and storing them using templates: $1$ (refers to first group match) and $2$ (refers to second group match)

**2. Retrieve Values:**

Now, refer these values in your script by using the following syntax:

${insert_values_gn} (n refers to match no.)

eg:

${insert_values_g1} - refers to the first match

${insert_values_g2} - refers to the second match

To make it simple, You can think "insert_values" as list of strings captured using multiple groups **and** use 'n' (1,2,3 etc) as the index to retrieve the values.

Note: using templates, you can have any number of values can be retrieved using multiple groups and refer to them by indexing, using a single regular expression extractor.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is a more efficient way but this worked:

```
\*\*(.*?)\*\*.*\"\*\*(.*?)\*\*
```

[image]

You can also use only `\*\*(.*?)\*\*`
It will match both of them anyway, so make sure you set the right 'Matching No.' in Jmeter if you pass one of the values:

[image]

The Matching No should be 1 for the first, and 2 for the second match i believe.