# How can I set dynamic parameters in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[image][image][image]        My scenario
        Step1: I have set http request for my variable and values are

```
     courseid = ${courseid}            
     priceid = ${priceid}                     
     coursecategoryid = ${coursecategoryid}..            
     .....etc         

    Step2: I have set my regular expression extractor is

    1) courseid

    Reference name: Courseid               
    Regular expression: courseid=(.+?)&          
    Template: $0$             
    Mathch No: 0                

    2)Price id              
    Reference name: Priceid                 
    Regular expression: priceid=(.+?)&                       
    Template: $0$                   
    Mathch No: 0     

    3)coursecategory id                       

    Reference name: Coursecategoryid               
    Regular expression: coursecategoryid=(.+?)&                  
    Template: $0$                 
    Mathch No: 0                  

    My result is showing below error in view result tree
```

http://192.168.2.41:8092/ecloudbaseweb//app/managecourseinfo?courseid=${courseid}&coursetitle=Maths&coursesubtitle=&coursedescription=Maths&coursegoal=Maths&coursepromevideopath=815%2Fpromovideo%2Ffile_19_Sep_2016_16_05_32_Promovideo.mp4&priceid=${priceid}&price=0&coursecategoryid=${coursecategoryid}

```
Kindly give me a solution for how can i using dynamic parameter for this scenario and kindly refer the snapshots
```

Comment: Why do you use `Template: $0$` and `Match No: 0`? You are supposed to need `$1$` in Template (first group of regex, a value in your parentheses). And `Match No: 0` - is a selecting of Random value (in the case of multiple matches of regex in a source string. Possibly, you can use just a `Match No: 1` - first match). Could you please attach your jmx-scenario? And what do you parse with regular expressions?

Comment: By the way, reference name is case sensitive. So `Reference name: Coursecategoryid` is a `${Coursecategoryid}`, not a `${coursecategoryid}`

Comment: i have updated you mentioned parameter details...but, the same error occurred...

Comment: Good, and your regular expression extractor, please.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to follow these steps to find and fix the problem:

1. Add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) - to know which values are captured using regular expression extractor.
2. If you are capturing more than one value from single response (using multiple groups), Follow the steps mentioned in the following post to check/confirm whether you are using regular expression in right manner: [using Regular Expression Extractor to capture multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478983/how-to-extract-multiple-values-with-a-regular-expression-in-jmeter/39547786#39547786)
3. Run the script and check the debug sampler (in View Results Tree) for the values retrieved by Regular Expression Extractor

**Note:** Regular Expression Extractor should be added as a child of the sampler, in which response regular expressions should be applied.

**Note:** Reference names used in regular expression are case-sensitive.

**Note:** If a single group captures more than one value, then specify index which value to be used in the request. match 0 - random value, match n - value in 'n' index.

Eg: Suppose Regular expression: courseid=(.+?)& , captures more than one courseid from the response, then you need to specify the match to retrieve specific value. Check Debug Sample result to know the values captured using View Results Tree.

**Edit:**

As you are naming "Reference Name" as 'Courseid' but using it as '${courseid}', it won't match. Use '${Courseid}', i.e., upper case 'c'.

Reg Expr Extractor:

[image]

Usage:

[image]