# Extract a value from actionlink html response body - JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a response body from one `http request` and I have to extract all the values and as input to another `http request`

```html
<a class="action-link" 
 regionName="region name"
 jName="a country"
 alertID="179"
 onclick="showDetail(this)"> Snapshot- v4 (Active) 
</a>
```

i tried with `regex` like

1. created a `post processors -> regular expression extractors`
2. Apply to `->` Main Sample Only
3. Field to check `->` Body
4. Name of created variable `->` regionNameVariable
5. Regular Expression `->` `<a class="action-link" regionName=(.*?)`

and passed the value as `${regionNameVariable}` in the next request.

But It is not working.
Can someone suggest the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that [using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not a very good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), consider using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) instead, the relevant configuration would be:

- Name of created variable: `regionNameVariable`
- CSS Selector Expression: `a[class=action-link]`
- Attribute: `regionName`

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/)

Comment: Accepting this answer. But it's capturing some values but not all. Thanks Dimitri T

Comment: Use `-1` as Match No.

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple Regular expression extractor to extract each values

For example to extract the 3rd group in regex of Region Name(You can write better Regx if you have better idea)

[image]

Like Wise Add Regex for jName and alertID

1. (jName)(=)\"(.+)\"
2. (alertID)(=)\"(.+)\"

Then Pass on the Reference name as user variable in your next http request.as ${regionName} and so on.

If you want to do it in the same Regex post Processor. Please refer [How to extract multiple values with a regular expression in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478983/how-to-extract-multiple-values-with-a-regular-expression-in-jmeter)

Comment: its not working Arjun. the request its passing like `regionName=%24%7BregionName%7D`

Comment: Toggle Encode field in parameter where you are passing regionName. Disable and check or enable and check.In case... Some versions of Jmeter are buggy. Also Make sure that the content encoding in the http request sampler is utf-8. Just type utf-8 in the text field of content encoding.